# Error: When convert spark dataframe to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to convert spark dataframe *(large datasets)* into pandas dataframe.

Code : `spark_df = Example_df.toPandas()`

I am getting this error:

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:145: UserWarning: toPandas attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true, but has reached the error below and can not continue. Note that 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' does not have an effect on failures in the middle of computation.

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 30 tasks (31.0 GiB) is bigger than local result size limit 30.0 GiB, to address it, set spark.driver.maxResultSize bigger than your dataset result size.
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The error is clear, you need to set `spark.driver.maxResultSize` so something bigger than 31Gb.

Longer answer: when running `toPandas`, you're requesting Spark to demand all executors to send data back to a single driver, and the driver's memory has to be big enough to hold that much data.